# R: Logistic Regression with L2-Penalty and output of coefficient significance

Tags: r, logistic, p-value, regularization

I'm trying to run a logistic regression with a L2-Penalty on a dataset I have. For the regression coefficient I also want to have the p-values of the signifance or at least the standard errors.
My plan was to do it with Python but unfortunately none of the package fulfilled my needs.

As I need a solution for this problem really quick, I thought to use R in this case. Unfortunately I don't have the time to read all about the package R offers, so I just liked to ask if there is any way to do the above mentioned in R?

Comment: That is an interesting question! I don't know anything about it, so I have quickly looked at the `CRAN Task View` at `Machine Learning`. There, a couple of packages were mentioned. The first I looked at, `penalized`, works with logistic regression and has a whole chapter devoted to why standard errors are meaningless, though they do mention how to compute them. Maybe check this out?

Comment: Though, as coffeejunky suggests, with such methods you may be better of asking whether something like a coefficient p-value makes sense with a L2-penalty. There's certainly a reason most packages **don't** include such metrics.

Comment: The `covTest` package is an experimental R package for significance tests with regularized regression (the paper introducing it is [here](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ftp/covtest.pdf)). I haven't used it, but it's by the folks who invented the lasso and who authored the `glmnet` package for regularized regression in R (glmnet [vignette here](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html)).

Comment: The bit about "real quick ... I don't have time" reminded me of `fortunes::fortune("brain")`.

Comment: I think you can simply use `mgcv` package, one of the default R package. Though `mgcv` nowadays is most famous for GAMs, but 15-18 years ago when it first came up, it was for penalized GLM. It can impose ridge penalty to glm coefficients. This feature is still available today.